# background image height cropped at lower resolution views

Tags: reactjs, slider, background-image

I have background image slider. Image height is 100vh, image parent div height is 100%. I tried to set image height 100%, but image disappeared. It is not flexible for mobile resolutions, when screen decrease, spaces appear down side. Also body and HTML is 100% height. I don't know the issue is height or issue is slider.

```
const bgImageStyle = {
        backgroundImage: `url(${imageSlide[currentState]?.url})`,
        backgroundPosition: "center",
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        height: "100vh",
        border:"3px solid blue",
        backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
    }

      <div className="container_style">
        <div className="bgImageStyle" style={bgImageStyle}><div/>
      </div>
.container_style{
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    border:3px solid rgb(88, 255, 66);
}

body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  border:3px solid green;
}

.App{
  border:3px solid rgb(255, 0, 191);
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

I need to be background image flexible mobile resolutions. Without white spaces down side.